# Set the value of a combo box with only part of the value

Tags: jquery, regex, combobox

I have a `combobox` like this

```
<select id="myCombo">
      <option value='alpha1'>A1</option>
      <option value='alpha2'>A2</option>
      <option value='alpha3'>A3</option>
      <option value='beta1'>B1</option>
      <option value='beta2'>B1</option>
      <option value='gamma'>C</option>
      <option value='delta2'>D2</option>
</select>
```

When a user enters *alpha*, I want to select all the options with values starting with *alpha*. But, `$("#myCombo").val("alpha")` doesn't do that, it works only for *gamma* `$("#myCombo").val("gamma")` understandably works perfect.

Also I cannot add a separate `class` to specific set of options.

Can I set value using `REGEXP`? Or any other workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#myCombo option[value^='alpha']").prop('selected',true);
```

Demo `------->` http://jsfiddle.net/g2UwK/6/

For `jQuery < 1.5` -

```
$("#myCombo option[value^='alpha']").attr('selected',true);
```

Demo `------->` http://jsfiddle.net/g2UwK/9/

Comment: Works perfectly in `Jquery 1.6+` , but fails at certain test cases in `Jquery 1.4+`.

Comment: @SangeetMenon That is because `.prop` is added in 1.5, that will not work in jQuery<1.5 , see updated answer , you need to use `.attr` instead

Comment: I had actually tried `.attr` before commenting, but it still showed a weird behavior of selecting multiple options wrongly...and somehow I am not able to replicate it in a fiddle....